# Can Gitlab container registry store containers at the group level or only at the repository level?

Tags: gitlab, containers, docker-registry

Using a self-hosted GitLab instance I can configure the GitLab container registry under a repository successfully. The repository is part of a GitLab group.

It would be more logical, organizationally, if the containers were stored as part of the group rather than as part of a repo (which I would just dedicate to the purpose of storing docker containers for the group).

It's not clear to me if I just don't know how to configure the GitLab group to be a container registry, or whether this just isn't possible.